# How do they not smell the body?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-lovely-bones

If Susie's body had been in a bag in Mr. Harvey's safe in *The Lovely Bones*, how did people who went into his house (Lindsey when she broke into his house through the basement window) not smell her dead body?